# Como ordenar 2 elementos en SQL Server utilizando el order by u otro?

Tags: sql, sql-server

El caso es que tengo 2 tablas llamadas reporteCoronavirus y Pais. Y yo quiero ordenar por nombre de pais y cantidad para tener el mayor... En este caso solo me ordena el nombre, y no funciona el ordenar cantidad tambien.

```
select nombre ,SUM (casos) AS cantidad , avg(casos) as promedio_casos 
from pais, reporteCoronavirus 
where pais.pais = reporteCoronavirus.pais 
group by nombre 
order by nombre,cantidad;
```

lo que arroja mi consulta es:

```
afganistan 50   
alemania 350       
belice 10
```

resultado que quiero es:

```
alemania 350
afganistan 50
belice 10
```

Comment: Deberías poner los datos que tiene tus tablas, también el código de la creación de tus tablas o el tipo de dato que tiene tus campos para recibir una ayuda mejor.

Answer (score 0):

En el escenario que planteas

```
create table ReporteCoronavirus (casos int, pais int)
create table pais (pais int, nombre varchar(100))
go
insert into pais (pais, nombre)
values
(1,'alemania'),
(2,'afganistan'),
(3,'belice');
go
insert into ReporteCoronavirus (casos, pais)
values
(100,1),
(100,1),
(100,1),
(50,1),
(25,2),
(25,2),
(2,3),
(8,3);
go
```

El problema según indicas, es order by, pero estás ordenando por nombre, cuando lo que pareces solicitar es ordenar por cantidad.

```
select nombre ,SUM (casos) AS cantidad , avg(casos) as promedio_casos 
from pais, reporteCoronavirus 
where pais.pais = reporteCoronavirus.pais 
group by nombre 
order by cantidad desc, nombre
```

[image: Resultado]

Order by funciona del siguiente modo. La expresión que estableces como primer parámetro (en el caso nombre) es el criterio de ordenación. Caso de que hubiese dos resultados iguales, entonces utiliza el segundo parámetro (cantidad). Al haber utilizado un group by, no vas a tener dos países repetidos, por tanto, te ordena alfabéticamente por país (en orden ascendente), y luego la cantidad.